# Using a batch file, how do I delete large, old files?

Tags: batch-file

I have temp files which are taking up a lot of disk space which I want to tidy on a scheduled basis using a batch file.

The file names I want to deal with always start with "harp_" but I want to keep the most recent 2 files.

For example the folder contains files such as:

- harp_0tnqy2o078824m1ax 25/10/2016
- harp_0e3qmw11gz6z9j10s 24/10/2016
- harp_0tnqy2o078824m1ax 23/10/2016
- harp_11ik03u00g4k2y19y 22/10/2016
- Test 1 25/10/2016
- Test 2 10/10/2016

I want the folder to just now contain:

- harp_0tnqy2o078824m1ax 25/10/2016
- harp_0e3qmw11gz6z9j10s 24/10/2016
- Test 1 25/10/2016
- Test 2 10/10/2016

Is anyone able to help me script the batch file for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. However, responding to your question as currently written:   I don't think so as provided text strings [are not valid file names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FOR /F` command to parse the output of the `DIR` command.  The key is using the `SKIP` option so that it keeps the two newest files.

```
FOR /F "skip=2 delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /A-D /B /O-D harp_*') DO del "%%~G"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite unsure if batch to bash is required. In case of batch my answer is like Squashman's adding an aspect of security, files to be deleted are added to a tmp-file which might be revised edited before execution.

```
@Echo off&Setlocal
Set Basefldr=C:\where\ever
PushD "%Basefldr%" ||(Echo Couldn't cd to %Basefldr% &Pause&Exit /B 1)
Set DelList="%tmp%\DelList.cmd"
Type NUL>%DelList%
For /f "skip=2 delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/A-D/O-D "harp_*"'
  ) Do >>%DelList% Echo:Del %%~fA
:: Review the file DelList.cmd before executing it
Notepad.exe %DelList%
:: or
::   more %DelList%
popd
```

Comment: The question was tagged with batch-file. What makes you think the user would need a bash script?

Comment: Pretty sure the user only wants to delete files that start with **harp_**.

Comment: Technically a bash is a batch. I thought the fokus was on the last 2 and didn't read correctly. BTW there was a drawn back bash answer.

Comment: drawn back probably, because it was bash, not batch.

Comment: So I wasn't the only one misled by the `/` not possible in a file name in Windows